# Bookmark compatibility among viewers

Tags: pdf

I use atril to view and okular to annotate pdf. It works almost well for me. However bookmarks defined in okular are not visible in atril (and vice versa). Is there solution to this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are Bookmarks in the PDF App that introduced them
[image]

Okular refers to those as Contents
[image]

Okular uses the term "Bookmarks" for an incompatible XML text database not physically stored in the PDF files. Thus unless there is an XML conversion mechanism Okular "Bookmarks" are not going to be of any value to any other PDF readers. They could be exported as removed XML plaintext and imported to a PDF using a PDF editor.
[image]
[image]

I can not find how Atril handles/stores "Bookmarks", it  should be like any other normal PDF viewer (using Acrobat syntax?)

In Evince they are called Index ! but as they are imbedded in the PDF they need to be edited using a PDF editor such as PDFtk.

[image]

Comment: I see, okular makes its own bookmarks for all pdfs. I tested few other pdf viewers/editors. It seems that there is no compatibility and each viewer sees just its own bookmarks.